# How to run parallel tasking with celery django?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am looking to run tasks in parallel with django celery.

Let's say the following task:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def loop_task(self):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
    return "done"
```

Each time a view is loaded then this task must be executed :

```
def view(request):
    loop_task.delay()
```

My problem is that I want to run this task multiple times without a queue system in parallel mode. Each time a user goes to a view, there should be no queue to wait for a previous task to finish

Here is the celery command I use :

```
celery -A toolbox.celery worker --pool=solo -l info -n my_worker1


-------------- celery@my_worker1 v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0 2022-08-01 10:22:52
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         toolbox:0x1fefe7286a0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

I have already tried the solutions found here but none of them seem to do what I ask [StackOverflow : Executing two tasks at the same time with Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570910/executing-two-tasks-at-the-same-time-with-celery)

I should have the following output:

```
0,1,2,...,9
```

If two users load the same page at the **same time** then we should have the previous output **appearing twice**

Result :

```
0,0,1,1,2,2,...,9,9
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need to start multi workers, but this does not guarantee that all tasks can be performed in parallel.

Will still has task in doesn't receive in queue. It depends on the number of workers and the speed of execution.

And if same result, you can set it in cache.

Comment: This is not a periodic task. This task is executed each time a view is loaded

Comment: Sry, I answered the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very simple to solve, but you need to test it.

Basically, you need to run task in async mode - for example, when you are trying to run task that send mass sms to multiple users, you do it in this way:

```py
send_mass_sms.apply_async(
    [
        phone_numbers,
        instance.body,
        instance.id,
    ],
    eta=instance.when,
)
```

Your code needs to be fixed this way:

```py
def view(request):
    loop_task.apply_async()
```

If you need to update data on website, you can store data in models and call ajax multiple times or implement logic via websockets, but this is topic for another question :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer but it doesn't seem to work the tasks run one by one